# How do I declare an array with a custom class?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I'm trying to declare an array with a custom class. When I added a constructor to the class, my compiler complains that there's "No matching constructor for initialization of name[3]".

Here's my program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class name {
  public:
    string first;
    string last;

  name(string a, string b){
    first = a;
    last = b;
  }
};

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  const int howManyNames = 3;

  name someName[howManyNames];

  return 0;
}
```

What can I do to make this run, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to provide a default constructor. While you're at it, fix your other constructor, too:

```
class Name
{
public:
  Name() { }
  Name(string const & f, string const & l) : first(f), last(l) { }
  //...
};
```

Alternatively, you have to provide the initializers:

```
Name arr[3] { { "John", "Doe" }, { "Jane", "Smith" }, { "", "" } };
```

The latter is conceptually preferable, because there's no reason that your class *should* have a notion of a "default" state. In that case, you simply *have* to provide an appropriate initializer for every element of the array.

Objects in C++ can never be in an ill-defined state; if you think about this, everything should become very clear.

---

An alternative is to use a *dynamic* container, though this is different from what you asked for:

```
std::vector<Name> arr;
arr.reserve(3);  // morally "an uninitialized array", though it really isn't

arr.emplace_back("John", "Doe");
arr.emplace_back("Jane", "Smith");
arr.emplace_back("", "");

std::vector<Name> brr { { "ab", "cd" }, { "de", "fg" } }; // yet another way
```

Comment: PODs can be in an ill-defined state ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow: They're not "ill-defined" - they're "uninitialized", which is conceptually well-defined, with the semantics that you mustn't read them.

Comment: Okay so what would be an example of something that *can* be in an ill-defined state?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Well, as I said, you cannot do it in C++. Hypothetically it would be something like making a static array of "unconstructed" objects -- anything in which an object is not in a well-defined state (e.g. trying to address memory as a class-type object without having completed a constructor). Maybe the new unconstrained unions offer more examples; there's plenty of UB there if you don't run your own destructors in the right order; hinting at ways in which you're prohibited from driving into an ill-defined state.

Comment: Er, `resize` requires a default constructible type.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Thank god nobody uses `resize` then!

Answer (score 5):

To default-initialize an array of `T`s, `T` must be default constructible. Normally the compiler gives you a default constructor for free. However, since you declared a constructor yourself, the compiler does not generate a default constructor.

Your options:

- add a default constructor to name, if that makes sense (I don't think so, but I don't know the problem domain);
- initialize all the elements of the array upon declaration (you can do this because `name` is an aggregate);

  ```
    name someName[4] = { { "Arthur", "Dent" },
                         { "Ford", "Prefect" },
                         { "Tricia", "McMillan" },
                         { "Zaphod", "Beeblebrox" }
                       };
  ```
- use a `std::vector` instead, and only add element when you have them constructed.

Answer (score 4):

You need a [parameterless constructor](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/oop-condestructors/constructors.html) to be able to create an instance of your class. Your current constructor requires two input string parameters.

Normally C++ implies having such a constructor (=default parameterless constructor) if there is **no other** constructor declared. By declaring your first constructor with two parameters you overwrite this default behaviour and now you have to declare this constructor explicitly.

Here is the working code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>  // <-- you need this if you want to use string type

using namespace std; 

class name { 
  public: 
    string first; 
    string last; 

  name(string a, string b){ 
    first = a; 
    last = b; 

  }

  name ()  // <-- this is your explicit parameterless constructor
  {}

}; 

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{ 

  const int howManyNames = 3; 

  name someName[howManyNames]; 

  return 0; 
}
```

(BTW, you need to include  to make the code compilable.)

An alternative way is to initialize your instances explicitly on declaration

```
  name someName[howManyNames] = { {"Ivan", "The Terrible"}, {"Catherine", "The Great"} };
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to create an array of objects, the objects need a constructor that doesn't take any paramters (that creates a default form of the object, eg. with both strings empty). This is what the error message means. The compiler automatically generates a constructor which creates an empty object *unless* there are any other constructors.

If it makes sense for the array elements to be created empty (in which case the members acquire their default values, in this case, empty strings), you should:

-Write an empty constructor:

```
class name {
  public:
    string first;
    string last;

  name() { }
  name(string a, string b){
    first = a;
    last = b;
  }
};
```

-Or, if you don't need it, remove the existing constructor.

If an "empty" version of your class makes no sense, there is no good solution to provide initialisation paramters to all the elements of the array at compile time. You can:

- Have a constructor create an empty version of the class anyway, and an `init()` function which does the real initialisation
- Use a `vector`, and on initialisation create the objects and insert them into the `vector`, either using `vector::insert` or a loop, and trust that not doing it at compile time doesn't matter.
- If the object can't be copied either, you can use an array/vector of smart pointers to the object and allocate them on initialisation.
- If you can use C++11 I think (?) you can use initialiser lists to initialise a vector and intialise it (I'm not sure if that works with any contructor or only if the object is created from a single value of another type). Eg:
  .

> ```
>  std::vector<std::string> v = { "xyzzy", "plugh", "abracadabra" };
> ```

`

Answer (score 2):

you just need to add a default constructor to your class to look like this:

```
class name {
  public:
    string first;
    string last;

  name() {
  }

  name(string a, string b){
    first = a;
    last = b;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class:

```
class name {
  public:
    string first;
    string last;

  name() { }  //Default constructor.

  name(string a, string b){
    first = a;
    last = b;
  }
};
```

Has an **explicit** constructor that requires two string parameters.  Classes with no constructor written explicitly get default constructors taking no parameters.  Adding the explicit one stopped the compiler from generating that default constructor for you.

So, if you wish to make an array of uninitialized objects, add a default constructor to your class so the compiler knows how to create them without providing those two string parameters - see the commented line above.