# Trying to Create an array holding a Struct in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct, constructor

I am trying to create an array using a struct in c++ which takes two variables i.e value and weight. So I created an array which will have value and weight in one element like this
Arr[]={{1,2},{3,4}}...and i want that if i called
Arr[0].value and Arr[0].weight then it should return 1 and 2 respectively but I think I'm doing something wrong because im getting many errors

```
    //Heres my Item struct....
    
    struct Item
    {
        int value, weight;
        // Constructor
        Item(int value, int weight)
        {
            this->value = value;
            this->weight = weight;
        }
    };



    //This is my knapsack function

    double knap(int n, Item arr[], double w)
    {
        double v = 0;
        double am = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            if (w == 0)
            {
                return v;
            }
            am = min(arr[i].weight, w);
            v += am * (arr[i].value / arr[i].weight);
            w -= am;
        }

        return v;
    }

    //Heres my main() function

    int main()
    {
        int n;
        double w;
        cin >> n >> w;

        struct Item arr[n];


        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            cin >> arr[i].value >> arr[i].weight;
        }
        //this is a fuction i want to run
        cout << knap(w, arr[], n);
    }
```

Here are the errors

```
  /storage/emulated/0/coursera/max money2.cpp:50:14: 
   errorr: no matching constructor for initialization of 
   'structt Item [n]'
        struct Item arr[n];
                    ^
    /storage/emulated/0/coursera/max money2.cpp:7:9: note: 
    candidatee constructor (the implicit copy constructor) 
   not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
        struct Item
               ^
    /storage/emulated/0/coursera/max money2.cpp:7:9: note: 
   candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
/storage/emulated/0/coursera/max money2.cpp:11:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 0 were provided
                Item(int value, int weight)
                ^
    2 errors generated.
```

Comment: `struct Item arr[n];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays must have their size denoted by a constant, not a runtime value.  Second, there is no need for `struct` here -- the code looks more like `C` than C++.  Instead:  `std::vector<Item> arr(n);`.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is `knap()` signature? Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: I've edited my post and added the errors image and also the knap() function @Slava

Comment: Btw `knap()` expects `int` as the first parameter and `double` as the last, but you call it with `double` and `int`. And your errors are not visible, post them as a text

Comment: I have added the errors as text ...

Comment: Please check it now

Comment: What do you expect the line `struct Item arr[n];` to accomplish? Construct `n` objects of type `Item`? How are they to be constructed without construction parameters? (That is what the error message is saying.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare an array with a custom class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579694/how-do-i-declare-an-array-with-a-custom-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest compile issues are this:

You got to give your `Item` a default constructor, otherwise, it can't exist in an uninitialized array.

```
struct Item
{
    int value, weight;
    // Constructor
    Item(int value, int weight)
    {
        this->value = value;
        this->weight = weight;
    }

    Item() : value(0), weight(0)
    {};
};
```

It appears you got your parameters reversed when you invoke knap like this.  Also, you pass the array without the brackets:

```
    cout << knap(w, arr[], n);
```

You probably meant:

```
    cout << knap(n, arr, w);
```

As others have pointed out with this:

```
    struct Item arr[n];
```

That's not valid C++, but g++ allows it.

Better:

```
    std::vector<Item> arr;    // #include <vector>
    arr.resize(n);
```

Then you pass it as an pointer to your knap function (which is written to expect it this way:

```
cout << knap(n, arr.data(), w);
```

Or alternatively, modify your knap function to take a vector:

```
double knap(vector<Item>& arr, double w)
{
    int n = arr.size();
```

So you can say:

```
cout << knap(arr, w);
```