# Can we treat a list of structs in C the same way as a list of classes in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

I used to program in C and I just moved to C++, while trying to learn OOP, I started working on a school management project.

I can use the constructor to create 1 object like this:

```cpp
Student student1 = Student(string firstname, string lastname, int Age, char Gender, int group);
```

how I can make an array of student class?

using **struct in C** I can do something like this:

```c
struct student{...};
struct student students[n] //n: number of student i want to add
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   students[i].name = ...; 
}
```

how I can achieve the same result using class?

Comment: You're very close with your code. Instead of `students[i].name = ...;`, use `students[i] = student(Put_Your_Constructor_Arguments_Here)`

Comment: In C you are using an *array* of structures (not just a structure). In C++ you would use an array of a particular *class* (i.e. a Student class). See [How do I declare an array with a custom class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8579694/4424636). So this is probably a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Unless `n` is known at compile-time, this won't work in C++. If `n` is a runtime value, use a vector.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo so i can do something like : vector<Student> students;

Comment: The linked question also shows how to use a vector.

Comment: @Greenonline I readied everything in the link, that's only worked for me using a vector.

Comment: Sounds about right. The link demonstrates use of an array with an initializer list and explains why you need to initialize all of the elements of the array when you define the array. basically, you can't do this with an array of a class without a default (no arguments) constructor because you need to invoke the constructor on all of the items in the array. Which means you have to already know what data is going in the array. Which you probably don't. Big take-away: Arrays are ancient tech, really simple, and very feature limited. In C++ there is almost always a better tool than an array.

Comment: @user4581301: To be fair, part of the reason that arrays are so bad is that `std::vector` has long been blessed with the magic, otherwise unavailable ability to create arrays without creating all their elements (immediately).  In C++20 `new` can finally do this, but that’s still really relevant only for the **rare** person implementing something like `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do the same kind of loop in C++. Except, you need to use `new[]` to create the array, as [variable length arrays are not part of standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/).

```cpp
class student{...};

student *students = new student[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
   students[i].name = ...; 
}
...
delete[] students;
```

A better option is to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead and let it handle the array management, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>

class student{...};

std::vector<student> students(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
   students[i].name = ...; 
}
...
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <vector>

class student{...};

std::vector<student> students;
students.reserve(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
   students.push_back(Student(params...));
   // or: students.emplace_back(params...);
}
...
```

Comment: Side note: `student *students = new student[n];` and `std::vector<student> students(n);` must still construct `n` `student`s, so you'll still run into the same "needs a default constructor" problem

Comment: @user4581301 the compiler will typically auto-generate a default constructor for you, unless other code in the class prevents it from doing so. But, in any case, it is possible to use `vector` with classes that don't have a default constructor. I have updated my answer with an example of that.